# Determining Planar Graphs

Tags: planar-graphs

Take a hexagon and add the three longest diagonals. IS the graph obtained this way planar?

I'm able to draw the graph very easily. But I don't really understand how to determine what graphs are planar and which aren't.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Walk around the hexagon and label the corners (in this order), "Water", "Jones", "Gas", "Smith", "Electricity", "Williams". Does that remind you of anything?

Comment: I don't understand where this is going. They alternate names and resources, but I'm not sure what that does.

Comment: @jerry2144: Are you familiar with the [utility puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water,_gas,_and_electricity)? You may have learned that $K_{3,3}$ is one of the _canonical_ non-planar graphs.

Comment: could i just use euler's formula? F - E + V = 2 where in this case F=1, E=9, and V=6. So this wouldn't be true and it would be planar?

Comment: @jerry2144: How do you get $F=1$? Solving for $F$ gives me $F=5$, which isn't  obviously impossible.

Comment: Note that the page I linked to (tried to link to; I somehow botched it up, but it's here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water,_gas,_and_electricity) contains a sketch of an Euler-based argument that does work.

Comment: My bad. F=6 if i'm not mistaken. So 6-9+6=2 which is false. So therefore, it isn't planar?

Comment: @jerry2144: Same question: where do you get $F=6$ from now? Note that the Euler characteristic applies only when you _already_ have a planar drawing; it doesn't make sense to "count faces" on a drawing with crossing edges.